# Making Replace or "/." stop after first replacement

Tags: replacement

After searching quite thoroughly, I haven't been able to find a good answer...
I'm looking to find an option for Replace to stop after it encounters the first rule which applies to some expression. 
Thanks

Comment: `replaceFirst[expr_, old_, new_] :=
 
 ReplacePart[expr, Position[expr, old][[1]] -> new]`

Comment: Or, much more hacky, `replacement = "A";
{"a", "b", "a", "c"} /. 
 x : "a" :> With[{res = replacement}, replacement = x; res]`

Comment: In some cases `ReplaceList[exp,rule,1]`can do the job. The problem is that the rule is only applied at level 0 of exp. Example : to replace 1 by 2 only one time in {1,1,1}, do `ReplaceList[{1,1,1},{a___,1,b___}:> {a,2,b},1]`. Result :  `{{2, 1, 1}}`

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a duplicate of the question indicated.  If it isn't, I suggest editing the question to give 1) an example input 2) an example set of rules and 3) the output desired.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I'll try them out,  
@mikado, the question indicated was exactly what I was looking for, probably I haven't been clear enough.